# Trying to Automate a Keyboard Shortcut, Have Tried both Pyautogui and Keyboard

Tags: python, automation, keyboard, pyautogui

I'm trying to automated a keyboard shortcut (ctrl+ e) I have tried both pyautogui and the keyboard function, however whenever I run my code instead of executing the shortcut in the application it executes in the command line. It literally just types "e" in the command line and I don't know how to fix this, it's driving me insane.

Literally no one else seems to be having this problem so I'm hoping that I can get an answer here. I have tried:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','e')
keyboard.press('ctrl')
keyboard.press('e')
keyboard.release('ctrl')
keyboard.release('e')
```

neither have been successful. My system is Darwin 18.6.0 if that helps.

Comment: program sends keys to active/focused window - if active window is command line then it send to command line. Did you try to use `time.sleep()` so you would have time to click application's window and make it active/focused ?

Comment: Yep this is the code right before I tried to automate:pyautogui.click(testcoords)
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','e')

Comment: maybe add in question more information about system. `pyautogui` works correctly on Linux.

Comment: Im running Darwin, could that be the reason why??

Comment: different systems has different methods to send keys and maybe Darwin has some restrictions. Maybe you can do it only when you run it as admin. You would have to search in Google `Pyautogui Darwin`. Or maybe you find some information on pyautogui's page - ie. [Pyautogui doesn't seem to work on macOS Mojave](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/247)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. `keyboard` can do the thing but you are using it the wrong way. You can create combinations using `keyboard`. Here is how to do it with `keyboard`:

```
keyboard.press("ctrl+e")
keyboard.release("ctrl+e")
```

Make sure to add delay before so that you can switch to your window